# Intermittent SIGABRT and SIGSEGV crashes in iOS app

Tags: xcode, sigabrt, segmentation-fault, ios

I have been noticing some crashing issues in my iOS application. However, I have been unable to observe a crash with any of my devices, so I am relying on crash logs sent to me from users. Here is a sample of 3 similar looking symbolicated crash logs (I cut off everything after the thread 0 stack trace, the rest of the crash logs did not appear to have any useful information):

Crash log 1:

```
Date/Time:       2012-11-07 16:40:21 +0000
OS Version:      iPhone OS 6.0 (10A403)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  SIGABRT
Exception Codes: #0 at 0x3c210350
Crashed Thread:  0

Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x00011350 __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x0006b973 abort + 95
2   libc++abi.dylib                     0x00003d4f abort_message + 75
3   libc++abi.dylib                     0x00000ff9 default_terminate() + 25
4   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00008a77 _objc_terminate() + 147
5   libc++abi.dylib                     0x0000107b safe_handler_caller(void (*)()) + 79
6   libc++abi.dylib                     0x00001114 std::terminate() + 20
7   libc++abi.dylib                     0x00002599 __cxa_current_exception_type + 1
8   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000089d1 objc_exception_rethrow + 13
9   CoreFoundation                      0x00008f21 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 457
10  CoreFoundation                      0x00008d49 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 105
11  GraphicsServices                    0x000052eb GSEventRunModal + 75
12  UIKit                               0x00057301 UIApplicationMain + 1121
13  TheApp                              0x000c7c17 -[StatusEditViewController grabData] (StatusEditViewController.m:75)
```

Crash log 2:

```
Date/Time:       2012-10-25 14:46:23 +0000
OS Version:      iPhone OS 5.1.1 (9B206)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  SIGABRT
Exception Codes: #0 at 0x35d1b32c
Crashed Thread:  0

Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x35d1b32c __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x34efc29f abort + 94
2   libc++abi.dylib                     0x35513f6b abort_message + 46
3   libc++abi.dylib                     0x3551134d _ZL17default_terminatev + 24
4   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x338c9357 _objc_terminate + 146
5   libc++abi.dylib                     0x355113c5 _ZL19safe_handler_callerPFvvE + 76
6   libc++abi.dylib                     0x35511451 _ZdlPv + 0
7   libc++abi.dylib                     0x35512825 __cxa_current_exception_type + 0
8   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x338c92a9 objc_exception_rethrow + 12
9   CoreFoundation                      0x35bfb50d CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 404
10  CoreFoundation                      0x35bfb36d CFRunLoopRunInMode + 104
11  GraphicsServices                    0x33996439 GSEventRunModal + 136
12  UIKit                               0x333d3cd5 UIApplicationMain + 1080
13  TheApp                              0x000c7c17 -[StatusEditViewController grabData] (StatusEditViewController.m:75)
```

And especially confusing, crash log 3:

```
Date/Time:       2012-11-12 11:00:21 +0000
OS Version:      iPhone OS 5.1.1 (9B206)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  SIGSEGV
Exception Codes: SEGV_ACCERR at 0x7142fa3c
Crashed Thread:  0

Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x314d8f78 objc_msgSend + 15
1   UIKit                               0x31c1d6d7 -[UIPrintPanelViewController dismissPrintPanel:animated:] + 50
2   UIKit                               0x31c920dd __73-[UIPopoverController _completionBlockForDismissalWhenNotifyingDelegate:]_block_invoke_0 + 284
3   UIKit                               0x318db4db -[UIViewAnimationBlockDelegate _didEndBlockAnimation:finished:context:] + 214
4   UIKit                               0x318d5aab -[UIViewAnimationState sendDelegateAnimationDidStop:finished:] + 470
5   UIKit                               0x318db3d5 -[UIViewAnimationState animationDidStop:finished:] + 52
6   QuartzCore                          0x3552ec2f _ZN2CA5Layer23run_animation_callbacksEPv + 202
7   libdispatch.dylib                   0x34838ee7 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF$VARIANT$mp + 194
8   CoreFoundation                      0x316662ad __CFRunLoopRun + 1268
9   CoreFoundation                      0x315e94a5 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 300
10  CoreFoundation                      0x315e936d CFRunLoopRunInMode + 104
11  GraphicsServices                    0x32ac2439 GSEventRunModal + 136
12  UIKit                               0x318eecd5 UIApplicationMain + 1080
13  TheApp                              0x000c7c17 -[StatusEditViewController grabData] (StatusEditViewController.m:75)
```

As you can see, these crash logs all have 14 entries in the thread 0 stack trace (not sure if that is coincidence), and the item at the bottom is the same line of code in the app. This line of code is pretty innocuous, it just calls a class method that displays a UIAlertView in the instance that the data entered on the edit view controller is invalid, and the strings being passed in are constants, not variables.

In crash log 3, there are references to a UIPrintPanelViewController, and while my app does have printing capabilities, there is no way to have the print popover and the status edit popover open at the same time, so I am not sure why it would be saying that it was trying to dismiss the print panel during the crash.

Does anyone have any hints or strategies on how I can attack this problem? (I am building against the latest iOS SDK and with Xcode 4.5.1.)

EDIT: Here is the offending line of code in the app:

```
[Utils msgBox:@"Entry required" message:@"Please enter a value for the Status field before tapping Save."];
```

And since this will probably be the subject of the next comment, here is the class method in Utils.m for msgBox:

```
+ (void)msgBox:(NSString *)inTitle message:(NSString *)inMessage
{

    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                      initWithTitle:inTitle
                      message:inMessage
                      delegate:nil
                      cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                      otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];
}
```

As the stack trace is not showing any record of going into the Utils class, I am guessing that something is happening before the class method is called.

Comment: Since they all seem to implicate line 75 of StatusEditViewController.m it would be nice to know what's going on in that neighborhood.

Comment: I have edited the question above to include the line of code, hopefully it will help.

Comment: Since you don't have a delegate for your alert view, that rules out one big possibility.  Does Xcode's Product->Analyze menu option show you any warnings?

Comment: The only warning that I get when I build or analyze is that my provisioning profile is expiring.

Comment: :::crickets::: Yeah, that's what I thought...

Comment: Try adding exception breakpoint(Exceptions tab -> add exception breakpoint), run with NSZombieEnabled. You may be overreleasing something i.e. [Something alloc] init] autorelease]; then releasing it.

Answer (score 0):

You get this because you called `[alert show];` from a background thread (from `grabData`).

Fastest solution:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
   [alert show];
});
```

*I know you already solved it (year ago) but maybe it will help someone else (like me).*

Comment: Wow, how is it that I did not consider this? I will put this in there and try it out for a while and see if the number of crashes tapers off. Thanks.